Honduras visa requirements for cruise passengers
My husband and I hold UK passports and are going on a carribean cruise in February 2025. One of the stops is Honduras where I believe they have just introduced a visa requirements for entry.
Will this apply to cruuse passengers who will only visit for a number of hours?

Ask your cruise line (or travel agent). Also they answer should not be taken as definitive, but for UK citizen should be ok, and in any case, you will get information if you get visa directly from ship (sort of "cruise visa"), and requirements/restrictions. With such information you may be able to better google. -- I expect some easier way but i suspect also that politicians undervalued technical and logistical difficulties of such policy so delays and exception implementation are expected.

AFAIK cruise passengers typically need to have the documentation required for all ports of call on the itinerary, irrespective of the time spent in each and/or whether the passenger disembarks or not.

There are quite a few existing questions if you search for cruise visa or similar: 1, 2, 3. Basically it depends, and cruise ships often have special arrangements.
